# "TS2339: Property 'mock' does not exist on type '(type: string) => Promise '." Unable to mock SQS Queue.sendMessage()

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking, nestjs, amazon-sqs

I am trying to mock a call to the SQS method `sendMessage()` that use in the SUT (System Under Test) as follow :

```
private async pushJobIntoQueue(network: Network) {
    await this.contactInteractionsQueue.sendMessage(
      JSON.stringify({
        type: 'calculInteractions',
        networkId: network.id,
        isInteractionsShared: true,
      }),
    );
  }
```

Here is my test that I thought to be trivial :

```
describe('NetworkService', () => {
  let service: NetworkService;
  let networkRepo: Repository<Network>;
  let memberRepo: Repository<Member>;
  let sqsService: SqsService;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        /*  ... */
        SqsService,
      ],
    }).compile();

    /* ... */
    sqsService = module.get<SqsService>(SqsService);
  });
    it('should put every network into queue', async () => {
      const networks = Array(20).fill(networkDataBuilder());
      const expectedAddedNetwork = networks.length;

      const queue = sqsService.initQueue('cm-contact-interactions');
      queue.sendMessage = jest.fn();

      expect(queue.sendMessage.mock.calls.length).toBe(expectedAddedNetwork);
    });
```

The TS error is trigger by the penultimate line on `queue.sendMessage` :

`TS2339: Property 'mock' does not exist on type '(type: string) => Promise '.`

Comment: You're accessing the mock service through the SqsService interface, which won't have _any_ test-related properties.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by using casting as follow :

`expect((queue.sendMessage as jest.Mock).mock.calls.length).toBe(expectedAddedNetwork)`